# how to use other module collection in another module

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, collection

I have a 2 Module `marketplace` and `followup` i want to use followup collection in marketplace module i want to send mail after save product

**marketpalce Module**

```
 public function newpostAction() {


        /**
         *  Check license key
         */
        Mage::helper('marketplace')->checkMarketplaceKey();
        /**
         *  Initilize customer and seller group id
         */
        $customerGroupId = $sellerGroupId = $customerStatus = '';
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $sellerGroupId = Mage::helper('marketplace')->getGroupId();
        $customerStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCustomerstatus();
        if (!$this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn() && $customerGroupId != $sellerGroupId) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('You must have a Seller Account to access this page'));
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/seller/login');
            return;
        }
        /**
         *  Checking whether customer approved or not  
         */
        if ($customerStatus != 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Admin Approval is required. Please wait until admin confirms your Seller Account'));
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/seller/login');
            return;
        }
        /**
         *  Initializing variables
         */
        $productNameTrim = $set = $setbase = $type = $store = $sellerId = '';
        /**
         *  Getting  product values       
         */
        $type = $this->getRequest()->getPost('type');
        /**
         *  Attribute set 
         */
        $set = $this->getRequest()->getPost('set');
       $setbase = $this->getRequest()->getPost('setbase');
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getPost('store');
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $sellerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
        /**
         *  Getting group id
         */
        $groupId = Mage::helper('marketplace')->getGroupId();
        /**
         *  Getting product data from product array
         */
        $productData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product');

        $silkType = $productData['silktype'];

        /**
         *  Getting product categories from category_ids array    
         */
        $categoryIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('category_ids');
        if (!empty($productData['name']) && !empty($productData['description']) && isset($productData['price']) && isset($productData['stock_data']['qty']) && !empty($type)) {
            /**
             *  Initilize product weight
             */
            if ($type == 'simple') {
                if (!isset($productData['weight'])) {
                    $productData['weight'] = 0;
                }
            }
            /**
             *  Assing product short description     
             */
            if (!empty($productData['short_description'])) {
                $productData['short_description'] = $productData['short_description'];
            }
            /**
             *  Assign create at time
             */
            $createdAt = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate();

            /**
             *  Getting instance for catalog product collection       
             */
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            /**
             *  Initialize product sku 
             */         

            if(isset($productData['sku'])){
                $skuProductId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getIdBySku(trim($productData['sku']));        
            if(!empty($skuProductId)){
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('SKU Not Available'));
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/new/');
                return;
            }
            }           


            /**
             *  Initialize product attribute set id
             */
            if (!empty($set)) {
            $product->setAttributeSetId($set);
            }else{           
            $sDefaultAttributeSetId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                ->getDefaultAttributeSetId();  
            $product->setAttributeSetId($sDefaultAttributeSetId);
            }    

            /**
             *  Initialize product type
             */
            if (isset($type)) {
                $product->setTypeId($type);
            }


            /**
             *  Initialize product categories
             */
            if (isset($categoryIds)) {
                $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
            }
            $product->setSilktype($silkType);

            /**
             *  Storing product data's to all store view 
             */
            $product->setStoreId(0);

            /**
             *  Initialize product create at time
             */
            if (isset($createdAt)) {
                $product->setCreatedAt($createdAt);
            }
            /**
             *  Initialize seller id  
             */
            if (isset($sellerId)) {
                $product->setSellerId($sellerId);
            }

            /**
             *  Initialize group id  
             */
            if (isset($groupId)) {
                $product->setGroupId($groupId);
            }           

            /**
             * Set is assign product 
             */
            $product->setIsAssignProduct(0);

            $uploadsData = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $filesDataArray = $uploadsData->getFileInfo();

            /**
             *  Checking whether image exist or not    
             */
            if (!empty($filesDataArray)) {
                foreach ($filesDataArray as $key => $value) {
                    /**
                     *  Initilize file name
                     */
                    $filename = $key;

                    if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'image') {
                        if (isset($filesDataArray[$filename]['name']) && (file_exists($filesDataArray[$filename]['tmp_name']))) {
                            try {
                                $imagesPath[] = Mage::helper('marketplace/marketplace')->uploadImage($filename, $filesDataArray);
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                                /**
                                 *  Display error message for images upload   
                                 */
                                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             *  Adding Product images       
             */
            if (!empty($imagesPath)) {
                $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));
                foreach ($imagesPath as $value) {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($value, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                }
            }


            /**
             *   Initialize dispatch event for product prepare  
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'catalog_product_prepare_save', array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest())
            );         

            /**
             *  Assign configurable product data
             */
            if ($type == 'configurable') {              
                $attributeIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('attributes');
                $isInStock = 1;
                if(isset($productData['stock_data']['is_in_stock'])){
                    $isInStock = $productData['stock_data']['is_in_stock'];
                }            
                $productData['stock_data'] = array();               
                if(count($attributeIds) >= 1){
                    $attributeIds = array_unique($attributeIds);                
                    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributeIds);                 
                    $configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();                  
                    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
                    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
                    $product->setConfigurableProductsData(array());
                }
            }

            /**
             *  Adding data to product instanse
             */
            if (!empty($productData)) {
                $product->addData($productData);
            }
            /**
             *  Saving new product      
             */
            try {
                $product->save();

                if($type == 'configurable'){
                    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                    $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
                    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
                    if(isset($productData['stock_data']['qty'])){
                    $stockItem->setData('qty', $productData['stock_data']['qty']);
                    }else{
                        $stockItem->setData('qty', 0);
                    }
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_backorders', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $isInStock);
                    $stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty', 1);
                    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
                    $stockItem->save();

                    //This section is what was required.
                    $stockStatus = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status');
                    $stockStatus->assignProduct($product);
                    $stockStatus->saveProductStatus($product->getId(), 1);
                }

                $productId = $product->getId();

                /**
                 * Load the product
                 */
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                /**
                 * Get all images
                 */
                $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
                /**
                 * If there are images
                 */
                if (isset($mediaGallery['images']) && !empty($store)) {
                    /**
                     * Loop through the images
                     */
                    $increment = 0;
                    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image) {
                        /**
                         * Set the first image as the base image                       
                         */
                        if($increment == $setbase){                      
                        $product->setStoreId($store)
                                ->setImage($image['file'])
                                ->setSmallImage($image['file'])
                                ->setThumbnail($image['file']);

                            $product->save();
                        } 
                        $increment++;
                        /**
                         * Stop
                         */

                    }

                }

                /**
                 *   Initialize product options                            
                 */
                if (!empty($productData['options'])) {
                    $product->setProductOptions($productData['options']);
                    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(1);
                    $product->save();
                }

                /**
                 *  Checking whether image or not
                 */
                if (!empty($imagesPath)) {
                    foreach ($imagesPath as $deleteImage) {
                        /**
                         *  Checking whether image exist or not    
                         */
                        if (file_exists($deleteImage)) {
                            /**
                             *  Delete images from temporary folder      
                             */
                            unlink($deleteImage);
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 *  Function for adding downloadable product sample and link data
                 */
                $downloadProductId = $product->getId();
                if ($type == 'downloadable' && isset($downloadProductId) && isset($store)) {
                    $this->addDownloadableProductData($downloadProductId, $store);
                }

                /**
                 *  Success message redirect to manage product page
                 */
                if (Mage::helper('marketplace')->getProductApproval() == 1) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your product is added successfully'));
                      $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $mail->setToName('user');
            $mail->setToEmail('testmail98@gmail.com');
            $mail->setBody('Send Test mail to you.....');
            $mail->setSubject('Test Mail');
            $mail->setFromEmail('testmail@gmail.com');
            $mail->setFromName("Send Test mail to you.....");
            $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
            $mail->send(); 



                    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotification') == 1) {
                        /**
                         *  Sending email for added new product
                         */
                        $templateId = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
                        $adminEmailId = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace/admin_email_id');
                        $toMailId = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/email");
                        $toName = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/name");

                        /**
                         *  Selecting template id
                         */
                        if ($templateId) {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
                        } else {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                    ->loadDefault('marketplace_product_addproductemailnotificationtemplate');
                        }
                        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerId);
                        $selleremail = $customer->getEmail();
                        $recipient = $toMailId;
                        $sellername = $customer->getName();
                        $productname = $product->getName();
                        $producturl = $product->getProductUrl();
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sellername);
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($selleremail);
                        $emailTemplateVariables = (array('ownername' => $toName, 'sellername' => $sellername, 'selleremail' => $selleremail, 'productname' => $productname, 'producturl' => $producturl));
                        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'));
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                        $emailTemplate->send($recipient, $sellername, $emailTemplateVariables);



                    }
                } else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your product is awaiting moderation'));
                     $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $mail->setToName('user');
            $mail->setToEmail('testmail@gmail.com');
            $mail->setBody('Send Test mail to you.....');
            $mail->setSubject('Test Mail');
            $mail->setFromEmail('testmail@gmail.com');
            $mail->setFromName("Send Test mail to you.....");
            $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
            $mail->send(); 

                    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductemailnotification') == 1) {
                        /**
                         *  Sending email for added new product
                         */
                        $templateId = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/product/addproductapprovalemailnotificationtemplate');
                        $adminEmailId = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace/admin_email_id');
                        $toMailId = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/email");
                        $toName = Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_$adminEmailId/name");

                        if ($templateId) {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
                        } else {
                            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                    ->loadDefault('marketplace_product_addproductapprovalemailnotificationtemplate');
                        }
                        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerId);
                        $selleremail = $customer->getEmail();
                        $recipient = $toMailId;
                        $sellername = $customer->getName();
                        $productname = $product->getName();
                        $producturl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId()));

                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($sellername);
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($selleremail);
                        $emailTemplateVariables = (array('ownername' => $toName, 'sellername' => $sellername, 'selleremail' => $selleremail, 'productname' => $productname, 'producturl' => $producturl));
                        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'));
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                        $emailTemplate->send($recipient, $sellername, $emailTemplateVariables);


                    }
                }

                if($type == 'configurable'){                
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/configurable/',array('id'=>$productId,'set'=>$set));
                return;
                }                

                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/manage/');
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));          
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/create/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                /**
                 *  Error message redirect to create new product page
                 */
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/create/');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Please enter all required fields'));
            if($type == 'configurable'){
                $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/selectattributes/',array('set'=>$set));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/product/new');
        }
    }
```

**Followup Module**

```
$sellerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $sellerId = $sellerData->getId();
    $seller_mail = $sellerData->getEmail();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', $sellerId)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_email', $seller_mail);

        foreach($collection as $item){
        $mycustomer_email =  $item->getCustomerEmail();
        $mycustomer_name = $item->getCustomerName();

        $template_id = 'customer_update';        
                     $email_to = $mycustomer_email;
                     $customer_name   = $cus_name;
                     $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
                     $custom_variable = $mycustomer_name;
                     //$custom_variable1 = $cus_email;
                     $custom_variable1 = $this->getRequest()->getPost('store_name');
                     $email_template_variables = array(
                        'custom_variable' => $custom_variable,
                        'custom_variable1' => $custom_variable1);
                        //'custom_variable2' => $custom_variable2);
                     $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_STORE_NAME);
                     $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                     $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
                     $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email);
                     $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);
```

How to use this please give me some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write below code to use collection of any module anywhere

```
Mage::getModel('groupname/modelname')->getCollection()
```

In your case code like below:

```
Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection()
```